# FirebaseMessaging callback not triggered while sending notification from cloud functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

client side code

```
final FirebasebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

   _firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String,dynamic> notification){
    print("onMessage : $notification");
}, onResume: (Map<String,dynamic> notification){{
    print("onResume: $notification");
}}, onLaunch: (Map<String,dynamic> notification){
    print("onLaunch: $notification");
});
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token){
    print("token is : $token");
});
```

server side

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();

  const payload = {
        "notification": {
            "body": postingUserDocumentSnapshot.data()['username'] + " commented on your post",
            "title": "You got a comment",
            "sound": 'enabled',
        },
        "data": {
            "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
            "senderId": postingUserDocumentSnapshot.data()['userId'],
            "postID": context.params.postId,
            "notificationType": "COMMENT",
        },
    };
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(receiverMessagingToken, payload);
```

I do receive notification in the system tray but the firebaseMessaging callbacks are not triggered. However if i send notification from google console those callbacks are triggered.
Can anyone explain me or suggest me on why those callbacks are not triggered while sending notification via `admin.messaging().sendToDevice`?

Comment: I guess the difference is that in the console you don't send the `data` part, right? See the last two lines in [this table](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages). It doesn't make much sense to me either. :(

Comment: we can choose to send data part from console. data:{click_action:'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK} is required to be sent for triggering any action when user click on notification. It works perfectly fine from console. However, when i send the exact same data from the function admin.messaging nothing is trigger. This is not cool. I guess we have to natively implement the notification portion.

Comment: that's true, sorry! just as a suggestion, debugging the flutter `firebase_messaging` plugin plugin it's not as hard as it seems, maybe you can check it out! I'll do it when I get back to a project that uses it.